# Defining routes for a angular module

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-routing

I have a mainApp.js file and I put this code on it:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

**//ROUTES**
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when('/index',
    {
        templateUrl: '/Views/Admin/index.html'
    }
     );
}]);
```

When I run my application without ROUTES section, everything is ok but when I add them to mainApp.js file I face with **$injector:modulerr** error in my 
browser.

I try clear browser cache, check html pages to be sure about including mainApp.js file and replace my codes with these:

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []).config(config);

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
function config($routeProvider) {
    $provider
    .when('/index',
    {
        templateUrl: '/Views/Admin/index.html'
    }
    );
}
```

But nothing happened and I face with that error again.

can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject ngRoute as a dependency, also refer the angular-router library,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

**Controller**

```
 var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', [ngRoute]).config(config);
```

**[DEMO](https://embed.plnkr.co/Vu5UvgUFaidEVfQh4Nio/)**

Answer (score 0):

I notice several problems :

- You have not declared the `ngRoute` dependency in `module` function.

It should be that :

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']).config(config);
```

instead of that :

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []).config(config);
```

- You have confusion in used objects : $routeProvider and $provider then.
  $Provider has no relation with mapping url.
- Why using a `/` before templateUrl ?
- `config.$inject = ['$routeProvider']` should not be needed.

Try that :

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute'])
       .config(
            function ($routeProvider) {

         $routeProvider
            .when('/index', {
                templateUrl: 'Views/Admin/index.html'
            })
       };
);
```